# Rounding Date to nearest Day in Javascript.

Tags: javascript, date, jquery-mobile

I'm storing data on a per-day basis in localStorage, and in doing so I want to use the date as the "primary key".

I'm using JSON.stringify() and .parse() to store data thus:

```
localStorage.setItem(datakey, JSON.stringify(dataObject));  
dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(datakey));
```

I want to use the date as the datakey, and the app will just overwrite data recorded earlier in the the day if you record again later in the day.

So I need to round the date to the current day, month and year.

At the moment I'm trying this:

```
selected_d      = $("#date-1").val();
console.log("The date is "+selected_d);
dateArray       = selected_d.split("-");
day             = dateArray[2]; 
month           = dateArray[1];
year            = dateArray[0]; 
datakey     = new Date(year, month, day); 
console.log("The datakey is "+datakey);
```

The reason for using split is that the #date-1 is a jQuery Mobile date and it comes in a yyyy-mm-dd format and I want to use standard UK dd/mm/yy format.

The out put of the the console logs is:

```
The date is 2014-02-18 
The datakey is Tue Mar 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

I know this is because Jan = 0, Feb = 1 and so on.

What I'd really like is some way of creating an "ideal" date object for me. One that only holds days, months and years and one which is in the format DD/MM/YYYY so I can easily query the localStorage. I know I can reconstruct the date by doing:

```
var displayed_d = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + "/"+ (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month_up + "/" + current_d.getFullYear();
```

but it's not really ideal, is it?

Any ideas?

Comment: new Date(JSON.parse('"2014-02-19"'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just form the key using the API?

```
var d = new Date(); // or wherever the date comes from

var key = function(d) {
  function two(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
  }

  return two(d.getDate()) + '/' + two(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}(d);
```

You could add that as a function on the Date prototype:

```
Date.prototype.getDateKey = function() {
  function two(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
  }

  return two(this.getDate()) + '/' + two(this.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.getFullYear();
};
```

Now you can get a key easily:

```
var dateKey = someRandomDate.getDateKey();
```

[MDN documentation for Date objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: This works great. I just run everything through this new getDateKey function and it seems all good. Let me experiment, make sure I can adapt everything to it and if so... well, it's die antwoord (the answer).